# HTML video tag does not display video correctly

Tags: html, cordova, video, ionic-framework

I am trying to use [Cordova Media Capture](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/index.html#capturecapturevideo) to play video however, it does not work.

Here is my JS:

```
function video() {

  navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(onSuccess, onFail, 
    {
      limit: 1,
      duration: constants.MAX_DURATION_OF_VIDEO
    });
  function onSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    console.log("MEDIA FILE");
    console.log(mediaFiles);
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].localURL;
        console.log(path);
        $state.go('submitMoment', {picture: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(path)});
    }
  };

  function onFail(message) {
    console.log("FAILED because: " + message);
  }
};
```

I have tried both FullPath and localURL.  I'm using localURL here because this video is being taken from the user's phone and I get an error from the browser. It is sandboxed so I cannot use a localURL coming from an external device.  The device returns a video in mp4 format.

Here is how it looks when I display it on the next screen in '$state.go'

[image: Video when user presses play]

The controls appear fine but when you play the video nothing happens.  It's just a white screen.

Once the video is done playing it just disappears:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<video width="100%" height="300px" controls>
  <source src="{{vm.picture}}" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
```

This is some strange behavior.  Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Console display:
[image]

[image]

This is the error I get when I use 'fullPath' because of this I decided to use the localURL instead and I don't get the error.  Also, it seems like the white screen bug isn't really a bug.  If i tap it the controls show up but it is still stuck on play (The first screenshot).

Comment: can you show what is displayed in the console?

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

In the onSucess method, store media url as

```
$scope.videoSrc = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;
$state.go('submitMoment', {picture: $scope.videoSrc);
```

Receive picture as $stateParams in your new Page.

```
$scope.videoUrl = $stateParams.picture;
```

In your HTML

```
<source src="{{videoUrl}}" type='video/mp4' />
```

In your controller inject the $stateParams dependency.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: fullPath doesn't work for me.  I edited my post to show the error I get.